# Algorithm to optimize polling frequency between producer and consumer

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to optimize what we call *AJAX request polling frequency* in the domain of web design. Here's a general version of the problem in simple lingo:

**Problem Statement:**

Suppose there are 3 persons - consumer (C), producer(P) and a messenger(M). The consumer and producer are some distant apart and can't communicate directly. The messenger - who works for the consumer - takes order from consumer, walks up to producer, places the order and come back to consumer. Messenger needs some finite amount of time to make the travel between P and C.

Now different orders require different amount of time for processing. After an order is placed, the M and C have no way to know how long the order processing will take. Hence, the messenger is required to make repeated trips to the Producer to check if the order is ready. It works in this way:

- Step 1: Messenger waits for W amount of time
- Step 2: M Goes to the producer to see if order is ready
- Step 3: a) **Order ready** - come back with the produced item
  b) **Not ready** - come back and repeat from step 1.

Now, I tabulated the time taken by each orders and plotted them against the number of orders taking that time. I got this:

```
   |                |  |             
25 |                |  |  |             
   |             |  |  |  |           
20 |             |  |  |  |  |  |         
   |          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |       
15 |          |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |     
   |       |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |     
10 |    |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |   
   | |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
0  +-|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|---
  1  5  10 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75 85 90
```

As you can see, most orders take around 35 to 40 units of time (let's say seconds) to complete whereas some orders get completed in 5-10 seconds and some takes 80-90 seconds.

**My Goal:**

It is costly to have a high-frequency W. Right now my messenger is checking back in every W seconds. Instead of keeping this checking frequency W as constant, can we find some other checking frequency - may be a variable one where we adjust the frequency as we go along - that would **ensure the least overall waiting time combining consumer and producer waiting time together**.

As you can tell, I am obviously not very good in articulating the problem very well. So, let me know if you need clarifications in comments.

***~~~ EDIT - Defining an Evaluation Model ~~~***

As some of the comments suggest, it's important to include W in the evaluation model. I think what I am really trying to do here is to minimize unsuccessful pollings (like polling that comes back empty handed as producer hasn't finished producing)

Say, messenger takes **W** amount of time to do one polling. If I take a given sample set of **N** pollings and if only ***S*** fractions of those polls were successful, then my intuition tells me that,

> *S = function (N, W)*

So the question is - given a specific set of ***N***, how do I find a ***W*** that maximizes ***S***

Comment: Is the wait time $W$ required to be a constant? Or can it vary, say, by how much time has elapsed since the initial request?

Comment: So what's the question?  Is the question, how do I find the optimal frequency $W$, that ensures the least waiting time?  The obvious answer is to poll as frequently as possible, as your evaluation criteria doesn't take into account the cost of a high-frequency W.  I encourage you to edit your question to clarify exactly what metric you want to optimize, i.e., what quantity you are trying to maximize.  Have you tried writing code to simulate the behavior with different values of $W$?  (Also, can you say anything about why you selected the linear-programming tag?)

Comment: Is the range 5-90 all you need to consider, or is this just a portion of the distribution of durations taken to complete orders? A specific cost model would be necessary to know what to optimize, like D.W. said.

Comment: @mhum - yes we may choose to vary it.

Comment: @D.W. - I have to agree I was struggling to include W into my evaluation criteria. In fact, I am looking for suggestion on how best can I do that. I have one idea though. I have edited my question just now to include that. (also I thought this may be a integer programming problem with binary unknowns - hence the tag)

Comment: @G.Bach - Yes, we need to consider the entire _set_ to come up with a suitable W (which may very based on a predefined logic) so as to minimize overall misses by the messenger...

Comment: The way to maximize $S$ is to make $W$ be very low frequency: wait 90 seconds before polling for the first time.  That's probably not the answer you wanted, though, which indicates that maximizing $S$ probably isn't the question you want answered.  Probably you need to think more on what you're trying to maximize/optimize, i.e., what the cost function is.

Comment: I agree with @D.W. -- if all you cared about was minimizing the wait time, then you'd likely poll as frequently as possible (unless the minimum polling interval was rather large, for some definition of "rather large") and if all you cared about was unsuccessful polls, you'd just wait a super long time to make sure you'd only poll once. I think if you fleshed out the real reason why you wouldn't just poll as frequently as possible, it might help formulate the problem and tradeoffs better.

Comment: You now clarified a bit, but without specifying the function you want to optimize, we can't help you.

Comment: @G.Bach the function absolutely does not matter. This question is not about optimizing a function. The function is a variable here. Question is - given a distribution function of some kind how do I find the pattern that mimic it closely.

Comment: @hashbrown I believe there might be a misunderstanding. The "function" that G.Bach is referring to is not the time distribution function. I believe that the function G.Bach is referring to optimizing is the notion of an objective function. Unless you have a clear way (i.e.: a function) to evaluate whether some method X is better than some other method Y, it will be difficult to come to a solution. You have identified at least two factors: waiting time and unsuccessful polls. How do you trade-off between them?